# how to know the jar name of the class being instrumented java

Tags: java, instrumentation

I am using java instrumentation.
Given the class name (which is being instrumented), how can I know the jar file it is in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work. I tried it with a single jar and it gave me the jar path:

```
new File(Test.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getFile())
```

Just replace `Test` by your class name.

Comment: I ran it 10000 times with a single class in a jar. The average time is around 6 nano second. Once again I've looked up only one class, this might differ in real life scenarios. However it shouldn't take much time....